# Heroku app deploy failed due to unknown reason

Tags: python-3.x, heroku

I have been trying to deploy an app to Heroku
it has been deployed but says `application error`

LOGS:-

```
2020-10-06T04:14:51.490040+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn great-usernames:wsgi`
2020-10-06T04:14:53.853073+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-10-06T04:14:53.889337+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-10-06T04:14:53.928653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-10-06T04:15:00.441714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=gg-usernames.herokuapp.com request_id=508d3db8-7a0b-4469-b22c-124117a6ffa9 fwd="49.37.6.95" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-06T04:15:00.982496+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gg-usernames.herokuapp.com request_id=d644c379-098b-4b37-927b-2578ca65537b fwd="49.37.6.95" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-06T04:15:14.860562+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=gg-usernames.herokuapp.com request_id=d2de73e7-9a89-453b-9e5f-0942f22e3ee6 fwd="49.37.6.95" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-06T04:15:15.333167+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gg-usernames.herokuapp.com request_id=43020ef1-b277-40a7-8555-2b71418f1917 fwd="49.37.6.95" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-06T04:16:38.957562+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gg-usernames.herokuapp.com request_id=97723735-ca99-4b00-818d-c36ac77867d6 fwd="49.37.6.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-06T04:16:39.649714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gg-usernames.herokuapp.com request_id=ca46ab12-0bf2-4e71-b3d5-f6760fd040d1 fwd="49.37.6.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-06T04:21:08.498502+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gg-usernames.herokuapp.com request_id=0a99c7bf-2a90-4bba-bbf1-46fc85bd3cc7 fwd="49.37.6.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-06T04:21:09.153869+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gg-usernames.herokuapp.com request_id=ed12acab-3296-4a09-b7fe-7b1f8fbcb25f fwd="49.37.6.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post requirements.txt?

Comment: @BeppeC is right, looks like you're missing `gunicorn` in your `requirements.txt` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify gunicorn and version in the requirements.txt

```
gunicorn==20.0.4
```